# How to skip ORM overhead in result?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an ORM sqlalchemy model, I need to construct a query (that is easier to construct with ORM classes), but it takes a huge amount of time. When I execute the same query directly as SQL to the database, it is quite fast.

Using the profile function provided in SQLAlchemy doc https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/performance.html I've found it is indeed the ORM adding a huge overhead.

However, the query result is used in several piece of code, so it would be a headache to change everywhere.

The query looks like this :

```
q = ( session.query(T1, T2)
  .select_from(sub_query)
  .join(T1, sub_query.c.id == T1.id)
  .join(T2, sub_query.c.id==T2.id)
  .filter(T1.user == 1)
  .order_by(T1.group, T1.position)
)
```

The rows are not modified, they are just read using the T1 and T2 attributes. (I mean, I don't need to get a T1 and a T2 object, just something like a raw object with attributes matching T1's and T2's column names)

Is there a way to speed it up (removing ORM overhead) so that I can access them with the same syntax e.g.

```
for t1, t2 in q.all():
  print(t1.x, t2.x)
```

?

I already tried `sqlalchemy.orm.Bundle`, but I get something like "Bundle is not selectable" (certainly due to the join)

Comment: If you don't want to use an ORM then don't. It's just a layer on top of the DB and you decide whether you use it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to continue using SQLAlchemy, but avoid the overhead of the ORM in this particular situation, you can use [`Bundle`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#column-bundles) as you've tried:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
from sqlalchemy.orm import Bundle

def to_bundle(cls, label=None): 
    return Bundle(label or cls.__name__,
                  *[c.class_attribute for c in inspect(cls).column_attrs])

q = ( session.query(to_bundle(T1), to_bundle(T2))
  .select_from(sub_query)
  .join(T1, sub_query.c.id == T1.id)
  .join(T2, sub_query.c.id==T2.id)
  .filter(T1.user == 1)
  .order_by(T1.group, T1.position)
)
```

You should not pass the bundles to `Query.join()`, but the mapped classes. The bundles will pick up the columns from the results of the joins. If you do pass the bundle you get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Bundle' object has no attribute 'selectable'
```

Comment: Really nice ! I like it ! I used a workaround that did pretty much what bundle does, but the way you show is definitively better and more pythonic. I just have one question : I tried to modify your solution to get the Table column list like this : `*cls.__table__.c`, but I get this error : `sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is available for object of type <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.query._BundleEntity'>`. Your solution works like a charm, but could you explain me why the use of inspect is required here ?

Comment: I used inspect namely for convenience and to gather the mapped columns in the bundle. This way one does not have to deal with other attributes of the mapped class, such as relationships, `@property` props, methods etc. I can't say that I know why you're getting that error, would have to try it out.